# Core Plot : how to render a color between two lines

Tags: ios, core-plot

This is my target.
And the problem is I'v no idea to render color between the line.

[image]

I will appreciate for any suggestion.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't easy right now. You might be able to make it work by creating a closed shape with the plot. Give it data points from left to right along the top of the curve and more points that define the bottom of the curve from right to left.