# Core Plot - Filling color for multiple plots with bounded confidence intervals

Tags: core-plot

I would like to plot multiple curves on a graph. These plots would have shading of a different color for each with certain bounds around them. Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions. I will really appreciate it.

Thank you,

Santosh

P.S.: I was not able to attach an image as illustration to understand the problem statement. My apologies. I have posted this question on the Google groups. Once approved, I will edit this post to add the link from there for the image.

Comment: Question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901383/core-plot-how-to-render-a-color-between-two-lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't easy right now. You might be able to make it work by creating a closed shape with the plot. Give it data points from left to right along the top of the curve and more points that define the bottom of the curve from right to left.

Core Plot issues [13](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/13) and [99](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/99) will address this problem, although there is no timeline for a fix right now.

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you for the reply. I was looking through the class structure in Core Plot and I found the method fillPathInContext [reference link](https://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg-history/efa73ee50d8edfd0e1d4294cf4bd2c07d9f8af77/documentation/html/iOS/interface_c_p_t_fill.html#a49257e4d49a04ec51b6dbafca8597add) in CPTFill class. Do you think this would be applicable to this problem? I cannot find a simple example which explains the implementation. Would this be a good approach?

Comment: The scatter plot uses that method to draw the area fill. You could also create a  `CPTBorderedLayer`, set the `outerBorderPath` and `innerBorderPath`, and attach it to the plot area or plot as an annotation. You can use the plot space to convert data points to drawing coordinates to use when drawing the paths.

Comment: I will definitely read about CPTBorderedLayer to see how I can use it. However, I was able to utilize areaFill and areaBaseValue to create a closed loop and fill color. I tried it on a simple rectangle first but I will apply them on the actual data plots next.